# Why is no symlink of "current" to release in deployer created?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, php-deployer

I am using for deployment bitbucket pipelines with deployer.
Previously a symlink with name "current" to the deployed release, for example

```
ln -s release/6 current
```

has been created.
When I start the pipeline now I got an error but no error message in the output of the bitbucket pipeline console. On the deployment server a symlink with the name of "release" to the current release folder has been created. In that folder all files have been deployed.
If I then manually create a symlink of name "current" like:

```
ln -s release current
```

everything is working.

So, why is no symlink of "current" to release in deployer created?